# the image on IGListKit view cell got blink every time i performUpdate

Tags: ios, iphone, image, uicollectionview, iglistkit

i am using this method to update my cell when there is a changes like someone send messages to me

```
adapter.performUpdates(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

The problem here is each time the IGListKit perform update, all of the image got blink every time there is a changes. Anyone know the solution ?